# Make Qt5 default for Cmake

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5

I am trying to build amarok in my ubuntu 12. I have installed Qt5 and Qt4.8.1 both in my PC. When I am trying to build and I am getting the following error in Cmake.

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108 (message): Could NOT find Qt4: Found unsuitable version "4.8.2", but required is at least "4.8.3" (found /usr/bin/qmake) Call Stack (most recent call first): /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:313 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE) /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1393 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS) CMakeLists.txt:83 (find_package)
```

Comment: Show your cmake file, where you are connecting Qt modules.

Comment: @SaZ http://pastebin.com/nS49BcHk I have pasted the whole errror. Please help me.

Comment: Check to see if qmake is in your system path.  If not, add it for the Qt5 version.  If it is, check that it's for the Qt5 version and not 4.8.1.  By the way, @SaZ was asking you to show the CMakeLists.txt file in the root of your Amarok sources, not more details on the error message.

Comment: I don't need your error. You already provided it. I need your cmake file, where you connect Qt packages and call qt macro. Did you read official documentation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Qt5 specific CMake functions, as documented on [the Qt5 CMake documentation page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/cmake-manual.html):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
find_package(Qt5Core)
```

Then there isn't any Qt 4 involved. Anywhere.